# sudo apt-get install (package name) always takes me to an Oracle Java 13 Installer, Where I cannot do anything

Tags: command-line, apt, java, sudo

I'm attempting to install a jailbreak utility known as Checkra1n using Ubuntu. This applies to all packages, running Sudo apt-get install (package name) always opens an Oracle Java13 installer, I had attempted to install this in the past, but the window doesn't allow me to do anything. There is an ok button, that does nothing. This happens to all packages, and it is very infuriating. Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few things to try in this order:

```
apt remove (Oracle Package)
apt purge (Oracle Package)
apt --purge remove (Oracle Package)
apt clean
apt autoclean
```

After running each one, do a reboot with

```
`shutdown -r now`
```

If that doesn't do it try:

```
dpkg --purge (Oracle Package)
```

Find the offending (Oracle Package) in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`*jdk-13*`.postinst` and edit. Add `exit 0` as the 1st entry (after #! /bin/bash)
Run `dpkg --configure (Oracle Package)` and finally `apt purge (Oracle Package)`

```
shutdown -r now
```